# Javascript slider not showing in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, mootools

We have an automatic slider on this website, http://www.realcapfinancial.com and it has been working on all browsers. IE9 doesnt seem to work. It comes up with and error, no object line 298... character 2 etc. I forget what it says but I can't check it again since I'm at work using a mac.

Any help is perfect, thank you

Comment: Your page is using Mootools, not jQuery.

Comment: It gets errors in Chrome too.

Comment: And Firefox on a Mac: Error: T$("calcclick") is null
Source File: http://www.realcapfinancial.com/
Line: 298 - likely because it does not exist until you have called the function where it is written

Answer (score 2):

The element with id calcclick is only added after the Resources tab is click. However, this element is already adressed (on line 298) on page load.

Comment: amadeus Thanks for your response. The one who developed this is no longer in contact. What can I do to fix this issue for IE9 - At least to make it show.